# Client connection in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, database-connection, pymongo, connection-pooling

How does MongoClient works and creates a connection pooling or thread creation?

What are major resources used if a create a multiple connections?

My main reson for asking is this ?
I have created multiple classes in python which represents functionality of single collection in mongodb. In each class i am creating a client

```
 self.client = MongoClient(hostname, port)
```

What resources i need to worry about and what can be performance issues?

**If there way i can share single client along all classes** ?

Answer (score 2):

Make one MongoClient. Make it a global variable in a module:

```
client = MongoClient(host, port)
```

A MongoClient has a built-in connection pool, and it starts a thread to monitor its connection to your server. For best efficiency, make one MongoClient and share it throughout your program.

Comment: What if the shared `client` is imported by a script that is run multiple times?